# Как подключиться к бд на другом пк (сервере)?

Tags: python

Объясните пожалуйста: использую базу данных - postgresql. Как мне получить доступ к ней, если она будет находиться на другом пк? Если у вас есть пример, для других бд - тоже возьму.

Comment: С точки зрения программы никаких отличий от соединения к серверу на локальном хосте  - указывайте вместо localhost/127.0.0.1 правильный адрес сервера (ip или доменное имя). Главное, чтоб по этому адресу сервер был доступен с того хоста, на котором запущена программа

Comment: хорошо, попробую. Спасибо!